# Given random variables A, B and C, is it possible that P(A>B)>0.5, P(B>C)>0.5 and P(C>A)>0.5?

Tags: probability, random-variable

As per subject. Do 3 random variables $A, B$ and $C$ exist, such that

$$
\begin{align}
P(A>B) &> 0.5\\
P(B>C) &> 0.5\\
P(C>A) &> 0.5
\end{align}
$$
?

It seems counterintuitive, but not downright impossible, or at least, I couldn't rule out the possibility that such random variables would exist. If we define $X=A-B,\ Y=B-C$, then obviously we're looking for $X,Y$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
P(X>0) &> 0.5\\
P(Y>0) &> 0.5\\
P(X+Y>0) &< 0.5
\end{align}
$$

But other than this, I cannot seem to make much progress.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_dice#Probabilities

Comment: Yes, see eg [this paper of ours](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290692?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miwin%27s_dice

Comment: @Xi'an very interested in your case since it seems to deal with continuous (or at least mixed) RVs. Any chance you could write an answer, summarizing and simplifying the paper a bit for us laymen?